# Cant get div to sit under other div flex box

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

[image]

So i want the Information & advice header to sit above the other div elements, however i cant seem to achieve this with flexbox. I thought assigning the container div to have a flex direction of column would achieve this but the header div still sits to the left of the other div elements.

html:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="headerWrapper">
        <h1>Information & Advice</h1>
        <h2>From The Daylight Experts</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <app-carousel></app-carousel>
        <app-guides></app-guides>
    </div> 
    <div class="instagramWrapper">
        <app-instagram></app-instagram>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
   .Container {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* you need this to move content side by side */
    flex-direction: column;
    /* provide the width for parent */
    width: 100%;
  }

  .headerWrapper {
    width:100%;
  }

  .mainWrapper {
    display: flex;
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 780px;
  }

  .instagramWrapper {
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
```

Comment: You need to apply the direction column to `mainwrapper`.

Comment: But that will make the instagramWrapper fall under the other div too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="Container">
      <div class="headerWrapper">
          <h1>Information & Advice</h1>
          <h2>From The Daylight Experts</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mainWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <app-carousel></app-carousel>
            <app-guides></app-guides>
        </div> 
        <div class="instagramWrapper">
            <app-instagram></app-instagram>
        </div>
    </div>
```

try that, you are applying flex to your mainWrapper which will align everything inside of it, take your headerWrapper out of the flex